# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'

Tags: android

I am trying to change the color of my action bar in android studio. I have already changed the minSDKVersion to 21 so I know that is not the problem. Yet I keep getting the error, I don't know what is going on. Here is my xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

Answer (score 7):

Use `android:colorPrimary`. `colorPrimary` on its own will only work if you are inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`.

So, for example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MaterialDesign/StatusBarColor), I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: So i did that, but the action bar is still grey instead of the color I wanted.

Comment: @AlexFritz: Are you testing on Android 5.0+? What is `@color/my_action_bar_color`? What other differences do you see between what you have and my sample (which is pretty much just "hello, world" with a tinted action bar)?

Comment: Android 5.0+ yes.  It is a red color, #F44336. I tried your exact xml, but I replaced all of them with my_action_bar_color, just to see if anything would change and nothing did.

Comment: @AlexFritz: Are you sure that you are referencing your custom theme in your manifest?

Comment: This line is in my manifest. android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > I changed the style to name="AppTheme".

Comment: @AlexFritz: Try running my sample project. If you get similar problems, the issue lies with how you are testing. If my project works, perhaps you can figure out what's different.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you also have any sample projects for the AppCompat `SearchView`? I am using the "SearchView" section in [this blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) to customize my SearchView but it is not working for me. I'll be thankful if you can point me to any sample project (if available ofcourse). Thank you.

Comment: @Solace: Well, [here is an `appcompat-v7` `SearchView` sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/SearchView), though I have not customized the `SearchView` itself much. If you have further questions on the subject, please ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually I did [here and also linked to an SSCCE project I posted online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912840/why-dont-appcompat-v21-searchview-styles-work-in-my-app) but nobody answered it. =s