# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary' Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android

I am in the process of using `colorPrimary` in my styles.xml file with `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as my theme.  I encountered an No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.  I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610974/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-colorprimary) as a reference but it did not match what I was looking for.  Here is my source code:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#690</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FlipPremiumOpenScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->

</resources>
```

Is there anything I have overlooked?

Comment: what version of the support library are you using?

Comment: I am using version 23.1, which is the latest.

Comment: Maybe you could create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload it somewhere?

Comment: <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFF000</item>

Comment: sumit, one problem with that.  I now get an error message that it requires an API level 21 (current min is 8).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#690</item>
```